# What is the best way to specify global and per-class configuration for a Gem that extends ActiveRecord models in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, rubygems

I have a gem that adds a certain functionality to ActiveRecord Models. I want a few parameters of this functionality to be modifiable, both at a global level, and at the time of adding my gem to each model, in case some models need different settings.

I'm doing this:

```
module Mygem
  @@config = nil

  def self.config(options={})
    defaults = {some_key: default_value}
    @@config ||= defaults
    @@config = @@config.merge(options)
    @@config
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def has_something_my_gem_adds(options={}) # method you call to add this functionality to your model
       options = Mygem.config.merge(options)

       # add functionality to the model

      define_method(:my_gem_options) { options } # I don't think this is the best way to store this, but I didn't find a better one.
    end

    def does_something
      if self.my_gem_options[:some_key]
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

I'm not very happy with creating the "my_gem_options" method, but I haven't found a good way to store that configuration information *for that model*, that would them be available for all the methods in my gem.

What is the best way to do this?

Additionally, I also don't what's the best way to store the "global" config for my gem, which I'm storing in `@@config` in the module itself. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using `define_method` dynamically, maybe a cleaner version would be:

```
module Foo
  DEFAULTS = {name: "foo"}

  def self.configure(options = {})
    @config = DEFAULTS.merge(options)
  end

  def self.config
    @config
  end

  configure({})

  def self.included(model)
    model.send(:extend, ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def foo(options)
      @foo_config = Foo.config.merge(options)
    end

    def foo_config
      @foo_config
    end
  end

  def name
    self.class.foo_config.fetch(:name)
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo

  foo(name: "bar")
end

puts Bar.new.name

# => "bar"
```

If you want to avoid storing the configuration in the model itself (which can be a good idea, but you lose some semantics, like inheritance), then you can have a hash in your main module:

```
module Foo
  DEFAULTS = {name: "foo"}

  def self.configure(options = {})
    @config = DEFAULTS.merge(options)
  end

  def self.config
    @config
  end

  def self.model_config
    @model_config ||= {}
  end

  configure({})

  def self.included(model)
    model.send(:extend, ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def foo(options)
      Foo.model_config[self] = Foo.config.merge(options)
    end
  end

  def name
    Foo.model_config[self.class].fetch(:name)
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo

  foo(name: "bar")
end

puts Bar.new.name

# => "bar"
```